# Add Result to TestCaseSource

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, nunit

I have simple method which calculates a given calculation from a list.
I would like to write some tests for this method.

I am using NUnit. I am using TestCaseSource because i am trying to give a list as parameter. I have the solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19479817/how-do-i-put-new-listint-1-in-an-nunit-testcase).
 My tests looks like this:

```
[TestFixture]
    public class CalcViewModelTests : CalcViewModel
    {
        private static readonly object[] _data =
            {
                new object[] { new List<string> { "3", "+", "3" } },
                new object[] { new List<string> { "5", "+", "10" } }
            };

        [Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(_data))]
        public void Test(List<string> calculation)
        {
            var result = SolveCalculation(calculation);

            Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo("6"));
        }
    }
```

I would like to test multiple calculations like with testCases.

TestCases have the [Result parameter](https://nunit.org/docs/2.5/testCase.html). How could I add a Result to TestCaseSource so i can test multiple calculations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this should work:

```
private static readonly object[] _data =
    {
        new object[] { new List<string> { "3", "+", "3" }, "6" },
        new object[] { new List<string> { "5", "+", "10" }, "15" }
    };

[Test, TestCaseSource(nameof(_data))]
public void Test(List<string> calculation, string expectedResult)
{
    var result = SolveCalculation(calculation);

    Assert.That(result, Is.EqualTo(expectedResult));
}
```

Comment: You don't need to also annotate with `[Test]` if you annotate with `[TestCaseSource]`. This should be fine: `[TestCaseSource(nameof(_data))] public void Test(List<string> calculation, string expectedResult) { ... }`.

Answer (score 13):

You can use [`TestCaseData`](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/writing-tests/TestCaseData.html) attribute for that. It allows you to encapsulate test data in a separate class and reuse for other tests

```cs
public class MyDataClass
{
    public static IEnumerable TestCases
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new TestCaseData("3", "+", "3").Returns("6");
            yield return new TestCaseData("5", "+", "10").Returns("15");
        }
    }  
}

[Test]
[TestCaseSource(typeof(MyDataClass), nameof(MyDataClass.TestCases))]
public string Test(List<string> calculation)
{
      var result = SolveCalculation(calculation);
      return result;
}
```